# QML access C++ model from parent component in nested object

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a C++ list model, where I can read data properly

model.h

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size);
//![0]

    QString type() const;
    QString size() const;

private:
    QString m_type;
    QString m_size;
//![1]
};

class AnimalModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum AnimalRoles {
        TypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        SizeRole
    };

    AnimalModel(QObject *parent = 0);
//![1]

    void addAnimal(const Animal &animal);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
private:
    QList<Animal> m_animals;
//![2]
};
```

model.cpp

```
#include "model.h"

Animal::Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size)
    : m_type(type), m_size(size)
{
}

QString Animal::type() const
{
    return m_type;
}

QString Animal::size() const
{
    return m_size;
}

AnimalModel::AnimalModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

void AnimalModel::addAnimal(const Animal &animal)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_animals << animal;
    endInsertRows();
}

int AnimalModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const {
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_animals.count();
}

QVariant AnimalModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_animals.count())
        return QVariant();

    const Animal &animal = m_animals[index.row()];
    if (role == TypeRole)
        return animal.type();
    else if (role == SizeRole)
        return animal.size();
    return QVariant();
}

//![0]
QHash<int, QByteArray> AnimalModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TypeRole] = "type";
    roles[SizeRole] = "size";
    return roles;
}
//![0]
```

main.cpp

```
#include "model.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <qqmlengine.h>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include <qqml.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickitem.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickview.h>

//![0]
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    AnimalModel model;
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Wolf", "Medium"));
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Polar bear", "Large"));
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Quoll", "Small"));

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setInitialProperties({{"model", QVariant::fromValue(&model)}});
//![0]
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:view.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

If I want to add a parent component to my listview, model is not accessible anymore because its visibility it's only from parent object. How can I expose the model then?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

//![0]
Window{
id: root

// how to catch here the model?

visible: true
width: 640
height: 480

ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: root.model // does not work

    delegate: Text {
        required property string type
        required property string size

        text: "Animal: " + type + ", " + size
    }
}
```

}

Comment: _I have a C++ list mode_ ... I see no model in the first chunk of code. What is this model? How do you expose it from C++ to QML? _model cannot be seen_ ... how do yu know that? do you get errors? Please clarify the question and provide [mcve]

Comment: @folibis I understand, but it does really matter since it works with a listview, and the question is not itself from the model? I didn't want to spam a lot of code not really pointed to the question

Comment: Ok, but I see no reason why `root.model` can be inaccessible from the list. So probably you've provided incorrect/incomplete code or something like this.

Comment: what is `required model`? a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that's really funny bug.
First of all, according to the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html) the property definition is:

```
[default] [required] [readonly] property <propertyType> <propertyName>
```

as you see the keyword `property` is mandatory.

The another issue is setInitialProperties says: *Note: You can only use this function to initialize top-level properties.*. So moving the `ListView` from the root item (and the `model` property too) makes this property inaccessible.

and one more issue is that the `ListView` already has a property named `model`, the attempt to redefine is incorrect. So you have to add some root item with the property `model` and that will solve the issue. Sure you will need to bind the `ListView.model` to this property

And the small example :)

```
Item {
    id: root
    width: 600
    height: 400
    property var model

    ListView {
        model: root.model
        delegate: Text {
            text: "Animal: " + type + ", " + size
        }
    }
}
```

`Window` can't be a root item since you use `QQuickView`.

Comment: `required model` comes from Qt example, it really doesn't seems a bug

Comment: Moving listview from top of course don't let model visible anymore, that's the point of the question. If I know how add a root property with the model, I shouldn't ask anything here :) could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Create an alias property in the root element with the same name of view.setInitialProperties allow to everything to work

main.cpp

```
view.setInitialProperties({{"mylistmodel", QVariant::fromValue(&model)}});
```

view.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window{
id: root
property alias mylistmodel : listView.model

visible: true
width: 640
height: 480

ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent

    required model

    delegate: Text {
        required property string type
        required property string size

        text: "Animal: " + type + ", " + size
    }
}
}
```